# Remote debugging using LinuxTools' Valgrind profiler in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, valgrind, remote-debugging

I have a program that I'd like to run remotely under Valgrind using the Linux Tools remote Valgrind profiler.

I normally debug remotely on a headless server (which has special hardware, so it has to be done remotely on that machine) using RSE, which works fine. Both my machine and the target are Linux machines.

I am now trying to get Valgrind working through Eclipse using the Linux Tools plugin. I have Valgrind 3.10 installed on the remote target machine, and I can run it up manually (outside of Eclipse):

Remotely:
     valgrind --vgdb=full --vgdb-error=0 /path/to/app --args

```
 vgdb --port=2345 --pid=XXXX
```

Locally, connect with gdb with `target remote host:2345`.

However, I can't work out how to get the "Valgrind (remote)" Eclipse tooling to emulate this, aping the "RemoteTools" setup shown here: [image].

When I write in a "To:" executable that starts with "rse:/", I get an error in the Profiling Tools settings window top corner saying `[Valgrind Options]: Couldn't determine version of Valgrind`. What should I write here to get a working remote Valgrind connection?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found more recent posts on the topic, maybe it will be useful for somebody. I also didn't manage to use remote valgrind plugin with RSE. Seems like only dstore connection type will work for Linux Tools remote valgrind, because SSH or FTP didn't work for me. [rseserver](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html) requires Perl and Java, and I didn't have them on my target.

I had to use this complicated solution via Launch Group combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741670/5239752) and [this](https://tromey.com/blog/?p=731) solutions. Preconditions: valgrind and vgdb are installed on remote target.

1. Write a script start_remote_valgrind.sh

   `set -x
   remote_ip=192.168.7.2
   remote_port=2222
   app_name=test_app
   remote_dir=/usr/local/bin/
   local_dir=/home/project_name/
   ssh -T root@$remote_ip killall -9 vgdb
   ssh -T root@$remote_ip killall -9 valgrind
   scp $local_dir$app_name root@$remote_ip:$remote_dir$app_name
   ssh root@$remote_ip valgrind --vgdb=full --vgdb-error=0 --leak-check=full -v $remote_dir$app_name &
   sleep 1
   ssh root@$remote_ip vgdb --port=$remote_port`
2. Create debug configuration Run->Debug Configurations->C/C++ remote application:
   2.1 On themain tab set the project name and app binary
   2.2 In the bottom of the configuration window click "Select Other" link and select "GDB (DSF) manual remote launcher"
   2.3 On Debugger tab set GDB debugger for you target platform, command line script .gdbinit. 
   2.4 On Debugger->connection tab set TCP connection, remote ip and port.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Create external tool Run->external tools->external tools configuration...
   [image]
4. Create Launch Group Run->Debug Configurations->Launch Group
   [image]
   external tool must be in Run configuration, remote gdb in Debug. The benefit of this approach is that remote valgrind output is printed in Eclipse console, so you don't need to launch vgdb manually in a separate console and see messages in separate window.